# How should I approach (in Python) to detect the change points in following time-series signal?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, mathematical-statistics, signal-processing, change-point

I want to extract different signals present in this image. To do so, I want to find the boundaries of change point at 2.429 GHz, 2.444 GHz, and so on. **Note**: These numbers are observed visually and might change after statistical calculation.
[image: In this image, X axis is frequency in GHz and Y axis is power in dBm]

Comment: Perhaps consider the frequency of the frequencies, and a low pass filter first and then rethink it. Or try a Gaussian, Laplace, or other stationary smooth, as appropriate to the space, whatever that is.

Answer (score 1):

The ruptures, changepoint or changefinder Python packages may do what you are looking for.  There is a tutorial on ruptures and changefinder [here](https://techrando.com/2019/08/14/a-brief-introduction-to-change-point-detection-using-python/) and the changepoint package [here](https://pypi.org/project/changepoint/).

As the tutorial notes, another option is to call the R packages directly from Python using rpy2.

Depending on what you are measuring you will need to think about the type of changepoint you are seeking to identify.  Has the axis been truncated or are values lower than -110 not possible?  Typical packages assume Normal distribution with a change in mean and/or variance but others allow for changes in other distributions, trend, autocorrelation etc..

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try out these methods.The axis has been truncated.